# Create WSDL message from SOAP Response

Tags: soap, wsdl

I have a WSDL that contains a different response then the actual responds with.  I want to update the WSDL with the format of the API response but am having trouble.  Is there a tool to generate a WSDL response from SOAP XML?

I should mention that they gave me the WSDL as a file, no public WSDL is visible.

The response contains this unknown anonymous xml element, s-gensym3.  It should be userid.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a .NET web service you can browse to [serviceurl]?WSDL to get the WSDL.

Comment: They gave me the WSDL as a file, no public WSDL is visible

Answer (score -1):

There's surely service endpoint you communicate with. You shall be able to invoke this endpoint in the browser and add to the end:

```
?wsdl
i.e. http://service:8123/operationName?wsdl
```

This will print you entire WSDL. Just make sure you have the same and you're done.

Comment: They gave me the WSDL as a file, no public WSDL is visible.

Comment: If your application is able to communicate with this endpoint, you must be able to print this WSDL.

Comment: Not if they don't generate a WSDL for you?  If you have plain webservices returning raw Soap messages doesnt mean there is also a WSDL available.  Like I said before I have a WSDL file on my side given by them, it wasnt found off the web.